# Aws Iot create rule error while creating new rule

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-iot

I am creating a new rule using the following command

```
aws iot create-topic-rule --rule-name my-rule --topic-rule-payload file://myrule.json
```

The content of `myrule.json` contents is

```
{
  "sql": "SELECT * FROM 'iot/test'",
  "ruleDisabled": false,
  "awsIotSqlVersion": "2016-03-23-beta",
  "actions": [{
      "dynamoDB": {
          "tableName": "my-dynamodb-table",
          "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::12345*****:role/my-iot-role",
          "hashKeyField": "topic",
          "hashKeyValue": "${topic(2)}",
          "rangeKeyField": "timestamp",
          "rangeKeyValue": "${timestamp()}"
      }
  }]
}
```

I am getting following error.

> A client error (InvalidRequestException) occurred when calling the
>   CreateTopicRule operation: 1 validation error detected: Value
>   'my-rule' at 'ruleName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must
>   satisfy regular expression pattern: ^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$

please can someone help?

Comment: The caracter `-` is forbidden in the `--rule-name` option. Try `aws iot create-topic-rule --rule-name my_rule --topic-rule-payload file://myrule.json`

Comment: i tried this  aws iot create-topic-rule --rule-name myrule --topic-rule-payload file://myrule.json

i am getting following error 
Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in topicRulePayload: "awsIotSqlVersion", must be one of: sql, description, actions, ruleDisabled

Answer (score 1):

The regex  ^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$ means you cannot use dashes(-) . Only underscore( _ ) is allowed